# Unable to read mails using Mutt client for gmail

Tags: mutt

This might be a bit off topic but i need a text based mail client.

I have configured mutt client for my gmail account as stated in the link http://lifehacker.com/5574557/how-to-use-the-fast-and-powerful-mutt-email-client-with-gmail

I am able to send mails, but I am not able to receive mails or open my inbox. Could any body kindly point out the mistake I am making?

Answer (score 0):

try below mentioned link. You need to set remote gmail folders
http://www.bartbania.com/index.php/consolify-your-gmail-with-mutt/